# How can i compare table colums in a fast way, 2 tables

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, sql-server-express

I have 2 tables, and i want to know how many of the records that are marked IsCkecked=true don't have a Data in Table2.
Then i need to mark them as false so they get prosessed a second time.

A second program is processing all the Table1 records and saving the data to Table2.

Table1 90.000 records
-Id
-IsChecked
-OtherData

Table2 60.000 records
-Id
-Data
-OtherData

I have this code and it does get the job done, but it's so slow. Compairing 60k times to 90k there must be a smarter way?
How can i do it better?

Can i use EF rather than Linq?

```
using DAL;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class ReadData
{
DataModelContainer model;

public static void Main()
{
new ReadData();
Console.WriteLine("Done");
Console.ReadLine();
}

ReadData()
{
this.model = new DataModelContainer(); ;

var idRecord = this.model.IdListSet.Where(x => x.IsChecked == true).ToList(); //90.000 Table1
var record = this.model.CompRegSet.Where(z => z.HtmlRecord != null).ToList(); //60.000 Table2
Console.WriteLine("This many ID's are marked: " + idRecord.Count);
Console.WriteLine("This many have data: " + record.Count);
Console.ReadLine();

int i = 0;
foreach (var item in record)
{
    foreach (var ids in idRecord)
    {
        if (item.Id == ids.Id)
        {
            i++;
            ids.IsChecked = false; 
            this.model.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
}

Console.WriteLine(i);

}    
}
```

Comment: your approach looks reasonable, is it that slow? or do you want to minimize code?

Comment: If you ordered both lists by ID number, then you could use for loops rather than foreach - and would not need to start back at the beginning of the inner loop.

Comment: Personally, for this sort of batch update scenario, I would write a single `update` SQL statement with a proper join between both tables and run that instead.

Comment: I assume `Id`s are unique so you could put a `break;` so you don't loop through unnecessary records. And what does `this.model.SaveChanges()` do? Can't you run that once when the loops are done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF is not optimized to read and update thousands of records like that. Among other things, you have to worry about a growing object cache, a large number of network roundtrips, etc.  There are ways to tune it, but you'll probably never achieve satisfying performance using EF.

In these cases, I think it's reasonable to use raw SQL so that you can let the database perform the whole operation in one go.  You can even wrap the SQL inside a stored procedure if you like.

In this case, you would probably write a single `UPDATE` statement that might look something like this:

```sql
update a
   set a.IsChecked = 0
  from IdList a
 where a.IsChecked = 1
   and exists (select null
                 from CompReg b
                where b.HtmlRecord is not null
                  and b.Id = a.Id)
```

If you at least have an index defined on `CompReg.Id`, you should get very good performance from this.

Comment: I was to focused on the code to think of that, thanks. Will try this.